# Display image button using function

Tags: python

I want to create many buttons. So, i have created a function and i call this function to create a button. The buttons have an Image so i have added on the parameter the link of the image when i call the function.

Knowing the Runtime error for Tkinter Image, i have used a list to save Image links.

The issue is that it display only one button. may be a problem with the list ?

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()

a = []
i = 0
def CreateButton (file, row):
    global i 
    global ButtonCreationImg
    global a
    a.insert(i, file)
    ButtonCreationImg = PhotoImage(file = a[i])
    ButtonCreation = Button(app, image=ButtonCreationImg, border='0')
    ButtonCreation.grid(row=row, column=0, columnspan=4, ipadx=0)
    i += 1



CreateButton("bouton_1.png", 6)
CreateButton("bouton_2.png", 8)


app.mainloop()
```

Comment: there is bug in PhotoImage which remove image from memory when PhotoImage is created in function and it is assigned to local variable. Maybe you should create global list for all PhotoImage.

Comment: to add element to list you can use `append(file)` and then you don't need `i` - and you can also use `a[-1]` instead of `a[i]`. You could also use `def CreateButton (a, file, row)` to send `a` to function explicitly - without using `global`

Comment: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` only for classes - ie. Button, `PhotoImage` -  and `lower_case_names` for variables - ie. `create_button()`, `button_creation`, etc. It makes code more readable and it is easier to recognize class in code. Even Stackoverflow knows this rule and it use light blue color for `CamelCaseNames` to make classes more visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect problem is with bug in `PhotoImage` and `Garbage Collector` which removes `PhotoImage` from memory when it is created in function and it is assigned to local variable - and which is removed by `Garbage Collector` when it exits from function.

You can read about this problem in `Note` on effbot.org: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

I use `button.img` to assign `PhotoImage` to class so it will keep it in memory.

I also made other changes in code but they are not important for this problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

# --- functions ---

def create_button(all_files, filename, row):
    all_files.append(filename)
    button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=all_files[-1])
    button = tk.Button(app, image=button_image, border='0')
    button.img = button_image # solution for bug with PhotoImage
    button.grid(row=row, column=0, columnspan=4, ipadx=0)

# --- main ---

all_files = []

app = tk.Tk()

create_button(all_files, "bouton_1.png", 6)
create_button(all_files, "bouton_2.png", 8)

app.mainloop()
```